# How to print specific rows in an r notebook document

Tags: r, printing, rnotebook

I have recently started using R notebook to annotate my script and share information with colleagues. I have a data frame similar to `data` created below:

```r
t <- data.frame(test=c("FirstPt_vs_LastPt", "FirstPt_vs_First3", "FirstPt_vs_First5", 
       "FirstPt_vs_First7", "FirstPt_vs_First10"))
n <- 5
test <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n,t,simplify=F))
Element <- rep(c("Copper", "Lead", "Zinc", "Bor", "Mag"), each = 5)
Region <- rep("alpha", 25)
p.value <- data.frame(p.value=sample(1:100,50,replace = T))

data <- cbind(test, Element, Region, p.value)
```

those are all the observations for `Region==Alpha`. In the same data frame, I have the same list of observations for several other `Regions`. For example, we will say the other `Regions` include `Beta`, and `Charlie`. I have been using: `subset(data, test == "FirstPt_vs_LastPt" & Region == "Alpha")`
to print the values of `FirstPt_vs_LastPt` in `Region == Alpha`. Then I have to make a new code chunk, type the same thing, and change `Alpha` to `Beta` to get the results for that region.

Is there a way to collect all the rows under `test` that are `FirstPt_vs_LastPt` and print the results for each unique `Region` like this?:

```r
Alpha

test                  Element   p.value
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Copper    … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Lead      … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Zinc      …
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Bor       … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Mag       … 

Beta

test                  Element   p.value
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Copper    … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Lead      … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Zinc      …
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Bor       … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Mag       … 

Charlie

test                  Element   p.value
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Copper    … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Lead      … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Zinc      …
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Bor       … 
FirstPt_vs_LastPt      Mag       …
```

And can the output be printed all on one page, meaning I don't the output to have multiple pages to scroll through, it would make more sense for my readers to see them all on one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the split function `split(data, Region)` which will return something like this:

```
$alpha
                 test Element Region p.value
1   FirstPt_vs_LastPt  Copper  alpha      28
2   FirstPt_vs_First3  Copper  alpha      88
3   FirstPt_vs_First5  Copper  alpha      16
4   FirstPt_vs_First7  Copper  alpha       8
...

$beta
                 test Element Region p.value
31  FirstPt_vs_LastPt  Copper   beta      44
32  FirstPt_vs_First3  Copper   beta      20
33  FirstPt_vs_First5  Copper   beta      89
34  FirstPt_vs_First7  Copper   beta      87
```

I modified your code to get the 'beta' into the dataframe. Also, try to avoid using function names like `t` for your variable names.

Comment: this is close to what I am looking for, except I want to do it for unique observations `test`. for instance, I want that output but only for the rows where `test` equals `FirstPt_vs_LastPt`. I tried using: ```data%>%
  subset(test == "FirstPt_vs_LastPt")%>%
split(data,data$Region)``` which didn't work, but may explain what I am trying to do

Comment: `data %>%
  subset(test == "FirstPt_vs_LastPt") %>% 
  split(.$Region)`